# Does Youtube iFrame setPlaybackRate() work in Mobile browsers?

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I've been using setPlaybackRate() for my youtube iframe and it works great on desktop, but on mobile it doesn't seem to work. Is this a known issue? Or am I missing something. There are no special mobile consideration for this in the documentation.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls